# how to stay on the last view after reloading the page (fullcalendar)

Tags: laravel-5, fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar in laravel 5.6.
My default view is the month view, and I want to stay on the last view after reloading the page.
example: if I switch to the week view, I want to be able to stay on this view week after refreshing the page and not return to the month view.
Thank you for helping me if you have a solution.

Comment: you'd have to store it in localstorage or something like that to persist the state and then set the default view based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really simple, just add the following lines to your .fullCalendar initialization:

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
  // when the view changes, we update our localStorage value with the new view name
   localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultView", view.name);
},

    defaultView: (localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultView") !== null ? localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultView") : "month"),
```

Rgds. Senad

Comment: hello,
thanks for your quick answer but i have this error at defaultview: View type "(localStorage.getItem (" fcDefaultView ")! == null? localStorage.getItem (" fcDefaultView "):" month ")" is not valid .
it does not work :-)

Answer (score 3):

For V5:

```
var iv = localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultView") || 'timeGridWeek'
var id = localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultDate") || new Date
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: iv,
    initialDate: id,
    datesSet: function (dateInfo) {
        localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultView", dateInfo.view.type);
        localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultDate", dateInfo.startStr);
    },
})
calendar.render()
```

Comment: Use `dateInfo.view.currentStart.toISOString()` instead of `dateInfo.startStr` because the latter returns first day on the calendar which in month view could be the last day of previous month.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery cookie library to store current view using the `viewRender` event and then use the follwing method to switch to it,

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'basicDay'  );
```

here is the reference for `viewRender` event which is triggered while you switch among views.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/viewRender

Comment: Hi thanks.
can you give me an example.
I started in web programming and I do not know anything about jquery cookie.
thank you in advance

Comment: i'm try this: 
->setCallbacks([
                'viewRender' =>'function(view, element) {
        localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultView", view.name);
                document.addEventListener(\'keydown\',(event) => {
                if (event.key == \'F5\') {
        sessionStorage.setItem("fcDefaultDate", view.title);
        $.cookie("exemple", view.start);
        }
    },false);

}',
 $('#').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agenda','$.cookie("exemple"')',
But it's this error : Attempting to call a FullCalendar method on an element with no calendar

Answer (score 0):

For V4:

```
viewSkeletonRender: function (view, element) {
   // when the view changes, we update our localStorage value with the new view name
   localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultView", view.view.type);
},
defaultView: (localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultView") !== null ? localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultView") : "month"),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with localStorage. For me it only works with localhost, but not on a remote server.

Instead I use ajax and php to store the variable in $_SESSION. Note that the startStr variable returns the first box date, which is the previous month if the  first day of the month is not a Sunday. This is corrected for in the php code, by adding 7 days.

Remember to include a session_start(); at the top of your main file.

PHP & Javascript in main file:

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['startdate'])) echo "var id = '".$_SESSION['startdate']."';";
else echo "var id = new Date;"
?> 

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

  initialDate: id,
  datesSet: function (dateInfo) {
    $.post("./setdate.php", {startdate : dateInfo.startStr}); // posts current view date for storage in $_SESSION
  },
  .....
```

PHP code (setdate.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
$date = strtotime(substr($_POST['startdate'], 0, 10));
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date); // the datestring relates to the first box, which is usually the previous month, so add a week to get to correct month
$_SESSION['startdate'] = date("Y-m-d", $date);
?>
```

My example only stores the month, not the view, but the code can easily be extended to include that.